# Proof of Hoelder's inequality for $p=1,q=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to prove Holder's inequality for the "boundary case", where the exponents are $1$ and $\infty$. This comes down to proving that $|f|\leq||f||_\infty$ a.e., where $||f||_\infty=\inf\{t>0:\mu(\{|f|>t\})=0\}$ is the essential supremum, since the rest follows from this by monotonicity of the integral. Is the following argument correct?

> If $||f||_\infty=\infty$, there is nothing to prove, so let $f\in\mathcal{L}^\infty(X,\mu)$. By definition of the essential supremum for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists a $t_n>0$ s.t. $t_n<||f||_\infty+\frac{1}{n}$ and a set $A_n$ of measure $0$ s.t. $|f(x)|\leq t$ for $x\in X\setminus A_n$. Summarising,
> $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\,\exists A_n,\mu(A_n)=0\text{ such that }|f|\leq||f||_\infty+\frac{1}{n}\text{ on $X\setminus A_n$}$$
> Let $A=\bigcup_nA_n$, then $A$ is measurable and $\mu(A)\leq\sum_n\mu(A_n)=0$ and we have on $X\setminus A=\bigcap_n(X\setminus A_n)$
> $$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})\,|f|\leq||f||_\infty+\frac{1}{n}\text{ on $X\setminus A$}$$
> That is, for all $n$ the inequality $|f|\leq||f||_\infty+\frac{1}{n}$ holds a.e. Finally, let $n\to\infty$, and we get $|f|\leq||f||_\infty$ a.e., which implies $|fg|\leq||f||_\infty\cdot|g|$ a.e., which implies $\int_X|fg|d\mu\leq||f||_\infty\int_X|g|d\mu$, proving Hoelder's inequality.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: You could also use that $|f| \leq ||f||_\infty ~a.e. \Longrightarrow |fg| \leq ||f||_\infty |g| ~a.e.$ and integrate